# Magento 2 : Area code must be set before starting a session?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, command

We have a custom console command and it was working fine in Magento 2.2.7 , when we move this extension to Magento 2.3 it failed when we running **setup:upgrade**.

Anyone who have faced exact similar issue. Please do help.

Comment: how is your command declared in `di.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the `di.xml` file

```
<type name="Vendor\ModuleName\Command\OrderQueue">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="state" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\State\Proxy</argument>
        <argument name="orderCron" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Order\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

you can also remove `$this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);` from the `configure` method

Comment: Sorry. fixed the typo

Comment: Please explain to me why this change and even in devdocs has nothing seems changed and more than anything how did you got these information I mean this method is working in 2.3. Please take time and give me some learning :)

Comment: You're simple terrific mate :) @marius

Comment: some of your dependencies or the dependencies of depencencies try to start the session and there is no area code when that happens. The solution is to provide proxy classes as dependencies so nothing else gets instantiated until it is needed.